# Java: How to insert multiple values in a more elegant way for preparedStatment?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, scala, prepared-statement

Below is my scala code, an insert query for Postgres which is to be passed to a `PreparedStatement`

```
val query =
        s"""
           |insert into structure_products (
           |identifier, "assetClass", "name",      "scoreType",
           |"field_1",  "field_2",    "field_3",   "field_4",
           |"field_5",  "field_6",    "field_7",   "field_8",
           |"field_9",  "field_10",   "field_11",  "field_12")
           |values (
           |?, ?, ?, ?,
           |?, ?, ?, ?,
           |?, ?, ?, ?,
           |?, ?, ?, ?)
           |""".stripMargin
```

then I have to do a manual set for 16 fields.

```
val statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)

statement.setString(1, identifier)
statement.setString(2, assetClass)
statement.setString(3, name)
...
statement.setTimestamp(15, field_11)
statement.setTimestamp(16, field_12)
```

So is there any other way to do this in a more elegant way? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Comment: Going off of the last comment, generally you would not want to implement an Object Relational Mapping architecture yourself.  Instead, you would want to use a JPA implementation like Hibernate or Eclipselink.

Comment: Have a look at http://playframework.github.io/anorm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [Anorm](http://playframework.github.io/anorm/), Not A ORM, but simple Scala JDBC mapper initiated by Play (I'm contributor of).

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the best approach in your case is to pass your fields and values to a function (as parameters) and generate your final INSERT statement within the function.